# Error while using if statement inside Map reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I am new to reactJS. I am implementing a Quiz page, where users can answer the questions and once they submit answers, the result is displayed. Following is the **DisplayResult** component which calculates the score and displays the result. I am getting error at the if statement. Checked the syntax multiple times, not sure if it is a syntax issue or if I am missing something. Could you please help.

```
import React from "react";
function DisplayResult(props) {
var score=0;
var Answers=[1947,1950];
props.data.map((dat, i) => 
    ({if (dat===Answers[i]) {score++}}
    ));
return<div>Your answers are {props.data[0]}, {props.data[1]} and your score is {score} </div>;

}
export default DisplayResult;
```

**Below is the error I am getting:**
./src/DisplayResult.jsx
Line 8:14:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

6 | var Answers=[1947,1950];
7 | props.data.map((dat, i) =>

> 8 |     ({if (dat===Answers[i]) {score++}}
> |              ^
> 9 |     ));
> 10 | returnYour answers are {props.data[0]}, {props.data[1]} and your score is {score} ;

Comment: Just a tip, try to use identention on your code, it make easy to you and others people to understand it.

Comment: Ok, will use indentation. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra parentheses on your map, it should be like this:

```
    props.data.map((dat, i) => {
      if (dat === Answers[i]) {
        score++
      }
    })
```

You should use a forEach instead of a map since you're suppose to have a return value in a map which is not the case here. See documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: it's better to use foreach than map since we aren't returning anything

Answer (score 2):

Use a `forEach` loop instead of `.map`.

By the way, you need to focus on the basics and fundamentals of `React`.
Try going through basic tutorials on Youtube.

```
const Answers = [1947, 1950];

function DisplayResult(props) {
  let score = 0;

  props.data.forEach((data, i) => {
    if (data === Answers[i]) {
      score += 1;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      Your answers are {props.data[0]}, {props.data[1]} and your score is{" "}
      {score}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoould not be using parenthesis and using the curly braces inside of it, it seems that you are used to conditional rendering notation:

```
    props.data.map((dat, i) => 
    (
{if (dat===Answers[i]) {score++}}
    )
);
```

write this instead:

```
props.data.map((dat, i) => 
   {
    if (dat===Answers[i]) {score++}
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach instead of map since you're not returning anything. And you're wrapping all you if statement inside ( ) which makes means map method is trying to return the whole thing and will throw an error.

```
props.data.forEach((dat, i) => {
      if (dat === Answers[i]) {
        score++
      }
    })
```

Comment: Got it, will use forEach instead of map, Thank you!